# How do I set JFrame's visibility to False after button click on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

UI2 is a JFrame that I have modelled using IntelliJ's Swing UI Designer --> GUI form.
I have added a button in this frame that will open another frame when it is clicked. 
I want to set the current frame's visibility to false after the button is clicked and before the other frame is opened. And I can't access the current frame in the button's action listener method. Any tips? Sorry if the question is unclear.

```
 public class UI2 {
        JPanel rootPanel;
        JPanel northPanel;
        JPanel westPanel;
        JPanel southPanel;
        JButton button1;
        JLabel header;
        JTextField textField1;



   public UI2() {
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
                frame2.setContentPane(new next_f().Panel1);
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame2.pack();
                frame2.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("UI");
        frame.setContentPane(new UI2().rootPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }}
```

Comment: you must save the other JFrame as instance variable in UI2

Comment: *"open another frame"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @tgallei I am not sure what you mean. I actually want to set UI2 frame's visibility to false before i open next_f

Comment: @Junaid you need a reference to the `JFrame frame = new JFrame("UI");` you created, then you can call `frame.setVisible(false);` the easiest way would be to make a reference in your UI2 class. You could also use `rootPanel.getParent()`, but I don't know how many times you would need to call it to get the JFrame.

Comment: @matt if u don't mind can u show me how to make this reference in my UI2 class, i am quite new to Java

Comment: Using rootPanel.getParent() works yes, but i really want to know how to make the reference to the current frame in my UI2 class @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to just add a field to your class.

```
public class UI2 {
    JPanel rootPanel;
    JPanel northPanel;
    JPanel westPanel;
    JPanel southPanel;
    JButton button1;
    JLabel header;
    JTextField textField1;
    JFrame showingFrame;
    ...
    }
```

Then in your main method. Change the set content pane to.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("UI");
    UI2 ui2 = new UI2();
    ui2.showingFrame = frame;
    frame.setContentPane(ui2.rootPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now everything in UI2 can access the showingFrame.

Comment: the line "ui2.showingFrame = frame" gives me an error of 'frame' being unresolved

Comment: @Junaid okay, I've updated it to include the full main method.

Comment: Thankyou, let me check